# Django Search Page with Query Pagination

Tags: html, django, url, django-views, django-templates

Hello i have implemented a simple search form and search view to show search result. Now i want to paginate them. But there is a problem with the page in the url. My search url looks like ../search?q=Bla

Now if i try to add pagination like: ../search?q=Bla?page=2 (at least thats how i understand it would work) it takes the whole string after q= to my database filter. I took a look at how stackoverflow handles searching and pagination and found out using '&' here is the view  code:

```
def search(request):
    # get query search parameters
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    query = request.GET.get('q', '')
    # query none or empty
    if query is None or query == '':
        return redirect('home')
    # query valid
    else:
        # icontains make sure to ignore character sensitivity
        post_list = Post.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)
        paginator = Paginator(post_list, 5)
        try:
            posts_l = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            posts_l = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            posts_l = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
        return render(request, 'search.html', {'post_list': posts_l, 'query': query})
```

and here the HTML Snippet:

```
{% if post_list.paginator.num_pages > 1 %}
    <div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links mb-5 mx-auto">
    {% if post_list.has_previous %}
        <a class="mr-3" href="?page={{ post_list.previous_page_number }}&q={{ query }}">zurück</a>
    {% endif %}
    <span>Seite {{ post_list.number }} von {{ post_list.paginator.num_pages }}</span>
    {% if post_list.has_next %}
        <a class="ml-3" href="?page={{ post_list.next_page_number }}&q={{ query }}">nächste</a>
    {% endif %}
          </span>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
```

So now the url is build like search?q=Test for the first page. And for the other pages (which suprisingly works) is search?page=2&q=Test. Now im happy it works but i dont quite how just adding `&q={{ query }}` solved my problem. Is this some kind of universal RFC? I dont quite understand since i was just checking out how this side does it. implemented it and works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [*query string* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) is the part after the question mark (`?`) of a URL. It is a string that consists out of a sequence of key-value pairs separated by an ampersand (`&`). The key and the value are separated by the equals sign (`=`). Both the key and the value are [*percent-encoded* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). So as you found out:

```
page=2&q=Test
```

is a querystring that contains two key-value pairs: `page` maps to `2` and `q` to test.

The code is however not entirely "safe". If the query itself contains an ampersand `&`, etc. then this can result in an incorrect query. You should make use of the [**`|urlencode`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-urlencode) to percentage encode the value:

```
<a class="ml-3" href="?page={{ post_list.next_page_number }}&q={{ query|urlencode }}">nächste</a>
```

Comment: This is great answer and wiki links also very helpful. thank you! If i type e.g. Test& in the search form the url encodes to search?q=Test%26, without the |urlencode filter in it or is this a different thing?